# How do I get query output as text in the pgAdmin v1.14.2 Query Tool?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I seem to remember an option in prior versions of pgAdmin where I could get the results of a query as text (like what one would get using the PSQL console) instead of the graphical "table" view. I cannot find a way to do that now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no such option in pgAdmin for the last ~ 7 years. Disclaimer: I am (low activity nowadays) member of the dev team.

A quick trick to display a text representation of rows:

```
SELECT t::text FROM tbl t;
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about that. It's still not the same as the PSQL console output, but cool nonetheless. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the data grid on the "Data output" tab as usually - select what you need and then copy/paste.

Comment: I don't really need to copy/paste the data. I just want to see it all uniformly spaced. The data grid columns never auto-size to the proper width, and when I adjust them they reset to their default (and wrong) state soon after.